# How to add a timestamp when a cell data is equal to certain values

Tags: excel, timestamp, vba

I am looking for a solution on how to enter 2 timestamps based on one cell's value without either one going blank when changed.

Example: Column A has a dropdown list for "COMPLETED" and "PENDING AUDIT" - I want a time stamp to appear in column 17 for that same row when PENDING AUDIT is selected. And once it changes from pending audit to COMPLETED for that same row, enter a timestamp into column 18. That way two timestamps are created from pending to completion and can be documented to analyze how much time it took from pending to completion.

Timestamp format to be "M:D:Y H:M"

Comment: Hi, could you please post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format columns **Q** and **R** to meet your requirements and then enter this small Event Macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim A As Range: Set A = Range("A:A")
   Dim v As String
   If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

   Application.EnableEvents = False
      v = Target.Value
      If v = "PENDING AUDIT" Then Target.Offset(0, 16) = Now()
      If v = "COMPLETED" Then Target.Offset(0, 17) = Now()
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I initially got it to do offset if it was blank before i posted the question, and wasn't sure how to proceed to do two different values. Your code was spot on!. Thanks again!